# Is "best" an adverb?

Tags: adverbs

In the sentence below, is *best* an adverb? If so, what does it modify, *left* or *are*?

> We’re best **left** alone.

Comment: Good question. My first answer was _yes, it is_. But I'm not so sure now. I don't think it modifies anything: I think it is the **head** of the complement AP _best left alone_, and so probably an adjective, with _left alone_ as its complement.

Comment: So, do you mean 'left alone' is a participial phrase?

Comment: It's a very greatly reduced sentence involving several idioms. Knowing an official label for a single word is of no help here.

Comment: @Listenever: on my analysis, _left alone_ is a adjectival phrase in which the head _left_ is a past participle. I am not aware of _participial phrase_ as the description of a constituent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Best* in your example is simply an adjective filling the role of the subject predicative. It describes the position of the speakers (‘in the best possible state’) if they are undisturbed.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a highly colloquial phrase which defies typical grammatical standards. Best is an adjective, and better is usually an adverb. To express the above sentiment with grammatical precision, one would have to say, "We are better if left alone." I think analyzing colloquialisms can be intriguing, but rarely results in an especially clear understanding of the underlying structural principles of the sentence or phrase.